# как соединить через inner join разные столбцы?

Tags: sql, sql-server

имеется две таблицы `table1` и `table2` и два столбца `text1` и `text2`. Как их можно соединить например через inner join, чтобы в итоге получить

| text1 | text2 |
| --- | --- |
| Не следует, однако, забывать о том, что консультация с профессионалами из IT обеспечивает актуальность направлений прогрессивного развития | прогресс |
| Практический опыт показывает, что реализация намеченного плана развития представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели развития. | эксперимент |

чтобы слово из `text2` находился из текста столбца `text1`

Comment: `WHERE LOCATE(table2.text2, table1.text1)`

Answer (score 0):

Через Inner Join не подскажу. Но есть вот такой вариант:

```
SELECT t1.text1, t2.text2
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE LEN(t2.text2) > 4 AND CHARINDEX(t2.text2, t1.text1) > 0
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы запрос искал больше 4-5 букв? Например запрос соединяет по одной букве: | книга | а |

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Приведи, пожалуйста, конкретный пример

Comment: ну например у меня соединяет в text1 | samsung7 | и text2 | 7 |, а хотелось бы чтобы их не было

Comment: @frehsmanboy Если я правильно тебя понял, тебе надо, чтобы условие выполгялось только для text2  длина которых больше 4-5 букв?

Comment: да верно, иначе слишком много строк получается

Comment: @frehsmanboy Исправил решение. Цифра 4 означает длину слова, можешь менять в соотсвии со своими нуждами